# how to insert multiple values of array checkbox in one row with different field name

Tags: php, javascript

i will use my old posted codes, coz i am working on the same program. what i want is how could i make it possible to save all selected values in one row which the studentid of a user will not be repeated. pls help...

```
     <?php session_start(); ?>
     <?php
     //server info
      $server = 'localhost';
     $user = 'root';
     $pass = 'root';
    $db = 'user';

        // connect to the database
      $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

      // show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
           mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
       ?>
      <?php
     $_SESSION['username'];
     $voter = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo 'Student ID: '. $voter.'';
     echo "<br />";
       if ($_POST['representatives']){
     $check = $_POST['representatives'];
     foreach ($check as $ch){
      global $voter;
      $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sample (studentid, candidate1) VALUES ('".$voter."', '". $ch ."')");
        echo  $ch. "<br>";
        }
        }
       ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <html>
 <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
function get_representatives_value()
 {
  for (var i=0; i < document.list.representatives.length; i++)

  {
 if (document.list.representatives[i].checked)
 {
 return document.getElementById('candidates').innerHTML = document.list.representatives[i].value

 }
 }
 }

 //-->
</script>
title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="candidate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body> <p id="txt"></p>
<form name="list" action="president2.php" method="post" onSubmit="return get_representatives_value()">
<div id="form"> 
 <?php
// get the records from the database
 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidate_info WHERE position= 'representatives' AND department ='CCEITE' ORDER BY cand_id"))
    {
  // display records if there are records to display
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
      {
       // display records in a table
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

     // set table headers
     echo "<tr><th>Student ID</th><th>Candidate ID</td><th>Course</th><th colspan = '3'>Name</th></tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
              {
     // set up a row for each record
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->cand_studid . "</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->cand_id."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row->course . "</td>";
  echo "<td coslpan ='5'>" . $row->fname . " ". $row->mname ." ". $row->lname ." </td>";
 echo "<td><input type ='checkbox' name='representatives[]' id='". $row->cand_studid ."' value='" . $row->cand_studid . "' onchange='get_representatives_value()' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
                                }
 echo "</table>";
                        }
     // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
                        else
                        {
      echo "No results to display!";
                        }
                }
       // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
        else
                {
             echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
                }

       // close database connection
       $mysqli->close();

echo "<input type='submit' name='representatives  value='Submit' />";

   ?> 
  </div>
 </form>
 <table>
 <tr><td>Preview List</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Candidates: </td><td id="candidates"> </td></tr>
  </table>
  </body>
 </html>
```

this the preview of my output and selected checkbox

[image]

now this is the preview of my database. this one is the result of my selection from the above preview which the student ID is repeated on my table.

[image]

what i want is to save like this

[image]

and one more thing, how could i make a preview of all i selected on the checkboxes, here is my preview output, below the table is the preview list of candidates as the user click on the checkbox. but it returns only one and only the last selected value as selecting multiple checkboxes will be printed. how could i apply this method in an array coz this preview, i remove the '[]' on my input type name='representative' and it works, but not in the presence of '[]'.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly you'd like to add candidate to student? How many candidate can a student have? The way you'd like to save it is not according to database normalization rules. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @HMR.. on my sample, a student can have only two candidate, and yeah i disobeyed the normalization and i'm aware of that, that's why i am asking help to correct it, coz i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: If there are only a fixed set amount of candidate values you could have them as columns in the student table. I think you're looking for an update statement for student and update the 2 candidate columns when you process the post.

Comment: @HMR .. so if that is, how i suppose to do that? i still have no idea..

Comment: I've added an answer with some pseudo code on how to update the sample table. If you'd like to normalize the database you have to put candidate in a separate table, delete entries with a certain student id and insert the entries posted when a user submits the form. You might like to read a good explanation about normalization (wikipedia article is not so good) and see mysql documentation on joining tables.

Comment: @HMR. thanks for your help and advice i really appreciate your answer...
and one more thing, does the method you answered(posted) is also likely the same in previewing the selected candidate on my javascript function?

Comment: Your preview question is answered I see.

Comment: @HMR.. thanks again for time and effort =) ...

Comment: @HMR.. yeah, and thanks to potatomeat...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I read your questions correctly, but...

**For your Insert Issue**

I don't know if the way you're storing the data in the database is the best method, but if you want to use what you have, you can just insert your record like this (assuming you've put in some validation script to prevent users from selecting more than 2 candidates):

```
<?php
$_SESSION['username'];
$voter = $_SESSION['username'];
if ($_POST['representatives']){
 $check = $_POST['representatives'];
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sample (studentid, candidate1, candidate2) VALUES ('". $voter ."', '". $check[0] ."', '". $check[1] ."')");
 }
}
?>
```

**For your Preivew Issue:**

I'm assuming you wanted something like this for your preview to show the studentid with the choices for candidate1 and candidate2:

```
<h3>Preview List</h3>
<table>
<tr><th>StudentID</th><th>Candidate 1</th><th>Candidate 2</th></tr>
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row->studentid . "</td><td>" . $row->candidate1 . "</td><td>" . $row->candidate2 . "</td></tr>";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for responding... your answer gives me what i need on my program. thanks a lot again..

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code you can use to update the sample table:

```
$candidate=array(null,null);
$candidateCounter=0;
foreach ($check as $ch){
    $candidate[$candidateCounter]=$ch;
    $candidateCounter++;
    if(candidateCounter>1){
        something wrong, only 2 candidates can be selected
    }
}
UPDATE sample set $candidate1=candidate[0], $candidate2=candidate[1] WHERE 
    studentid=$voter
```